# Need help with setting up eth-netstats and eth-net-intelligence-api

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, testrpc

I have set up an ethereum node on an ubuntu server. I'm running a geth instance with a miner in a private test net.

For the life of me I cant get eth-net-intelligence-api to monitor the eth-network.

So I've edited my app.json to reflect the correct servers and secret. And I've followed the install instructions on both githubs.

Additional question: will "WS_SECRET=abc npm start" to start the net-intelligence frontend be enough for the secret to work properly?

I think the problem is with the WS server. What exactly should I set the WS server to be?

Comment: See how the secret is used, and the value to use for WS server, in the answer below : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/48720/19779

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a good guide for this on the web, so I'll try to make this answer be one

[image]

## How to setup eth-netstats and eth-net-intelligence-api

### Installation

You need something to run a local blockchain ([Ganache](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) is great)

Install the beautifully named [eth-net-intelligence-api](https://github.com/cubedro/eth-net-intelligence-api) (it sits between the chain & eth-netstats)
(also need to install [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for running eth-net-intelligence-api)

Install [eth-netstats](https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats) (the actual lovely web interface to the chain data)

### Configuration

There actually is very little configuration required to get this started

In `eth-net-intelligence-api` edit the `app.json` file :

```
[   {
    "name"              : "aName",
    "script"            : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"   : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "merge_logs"        : false,
    "watch"             : false,
    "max_restarts"      : 10,
    "exec_interpreter"  : "node",
    "exec_mode"         : "fork_mode",
    "env":
    {
      "NODE_ENV"        : "production",
      "RPC_HOST"        : "localhost",
      "RPC_PORT"        : "7545",
      "LISTENING_PORT"  : "30303",
      "INSTANCE_NAME"   : "anInstanceNameIsRequired",
      "CONTACT_DETAILS" : "",
      "WS_SERVER"       : "http://localhost:3000",
      "WS_SECRET"       : "aSecret",
      "VERBOSITY"       : 2
    }   } ]
```

*Note :*
the `RPC_PORT` changed to 7545 for my Ganache chain
the `WS_SECRET` value is needed below

### To run

1) Start your chain (with Ganache this is a GUI)

2) **eth-net-intelligence-api**

`pm2 start app.json`

3) **eth-netstats**

`WS_SECRET=aSecret npm start`

4) Go to http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

I just started experimenting myself. I've got one node on my private network running eth-netstats (private IP 192.168.40.100 running on default port 3000). On all nodes I have eth-net-intelligence-api running and I point WS_SERVER to "http://192.168.40.100:3000",

One thing I found confusing: in the example the WS_SERVER had prefix "wss://...". Turns out it needs to be "http://..."

My app.json has:

```
  "NODE_ENV"        : "production",
  "RPC_HOST"        : "localhost",
  "RPC_PORT"        : "8545",
  "LISTENING_PORT"  : "30303",
  "INSTANCE_NAME"   : "ethereum_pi_0",
  "CONTACT_DETAILS" : "Joe",
  "WS_SERVER"       : "http://192.168.40.100:3000",
  "WS_SECRET"       : "mysecret",
  "VERBOSITY"       : 2
```